# [ERROR]: Record structure does not contain field image | Data Migration

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2-migration-tool

I'm having issues using the data migration tool ver: 2.2.6.
settings migrate successfully but when i run this command (data)

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --reset -a -r vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/config.xml
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR]: Record structure does not contain field image
```

I have tried to ignore in map-eav.xml but still no use

see my config if it helps
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This maybe late answer but @user72227 is right and you need to make sure that `map-eav.xml` was called in your `config.xml`

```
<eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml</eav_map_file>
```

Cheers!

> Mark this post as answer if this helps you.

Comment: thanks , i tried this but still the same error. check my options in config. maybe ive done something wrong

Answer (score 0):

In map-eav.xml, 
In node : source field_rules, 
Add :
ignore
    field eav_attribute.image

And retry.

Comment: thanks but still didn't seem to work. i also tried catalog_eav_attribute.image